# specific boxplot style

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, boxplot

I want to publish a paper but I need a good looking style for the image I create in R.

I found this amazing style in Nature Journal
could any one provide me with the code to get the same results ?

[image]

I made this graph but it wasn't good looking graph for publishing ...

```r
Elongation_İmage <- ggplot(PE_plot1, aes(x = Pa, y = EI, fill = as.factor(Risk_Group))) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.7, alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Elongation Index (EI)", 
                     labels = label_number(accuracy = 0.01)) +  # Continuous variable label
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Shear Stress", 
                   labels = c("0,3", "0,53", "0,95", 
                              "1,69", "3", "5,33", 
                              "9,49", "16,87", "30")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#4271AE", "#FF5A5F"), labels = c("Low Risk", "High Risk")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20", size = 12, angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="grey20", size = 12, vjust=0.4),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to change?  It would be easy enough how to show you how to have a blank background (`+ theme_minimal()`), unfilled boxplots with coloured edges (not actually recommended by data visualization experts: https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/avoid-line-drawings.html )  (By the way, plenty of people publish plots like this.  Looks fine to me ...)

Comment: Apart from formatting details, another chart type might better convey the essence of the depicted results which is (I think): "Low Risk" and "High Risk" show essentially the same elongation response. Why not use a scatterplot with coloured shear~stress curves instead of forcing the continuous stress values on an ordinal scale?

Comment: This looks similar to `ggpubr::theme_pubr` or even `ggpubr::ggboxplot`